# TI-OPA381 output voltage issue

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need help calculating the output value for the OPA381. My circuit (see image below) is attached to a photo diode with a dark current of 9nA. The Rf resistor is 5.2M ohm.  The OPA381 is set up as inverting amplifier so Vout is (9nA x 5.2M ohm). But why is the value 2.8? This is an exercise and I need justify my answer to my teacher.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: How do you know the current is 9nA? Can you put a meter on the simulated photodiode?

Comment: That photodiode model is wired backwards. Swap its terminals and see what happens.

Comment: I should correct myself: that photodiode is wired wrong, period. You need to provide a *reverse* biasing, connecting R3 to the negative supply and D1 to the positive through an appropriate resistor, then you get your signal from D1.

Comment: D1 polarity is **correct** but cct is unusual. Cct sets OA+ above ground to allow true zero output operation relative to OA+ | OA+ is at ~ 1k/(1k+10k) x 3.3V = 0.3V. SO OA will drive OA- to 0.3V also. So for Vout = 2.892 V V_5M2= (2.892-0.33)/5M2 = 493 nA. | Answer coming ...

Comment: I appear to be wasting my time here :-(

Comment: WHY? do you think it should be 9 nA? Where does the 9 nA figure come from? Have you tried reversing the polarity of V2 yet?

Answer (score 1):

D1 **output** polarity is **correct** but the circuit is unusual.
D1 **current source** polarity appears be wrong.
ie Swap V2 polarity and see what happens.
Circuit operation explained below as it is not quite the usual arrangement.

---

The OPA381 ( [superb data sheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2381.pdf)) is a precision single supply transconductance op amp.
It can swing its output close to but not completely to ground, so

- the purpose of the R10/R9 divider is to provide a pseudo ground reference 0.3V above true ground and this is the point that Vout should be measured with respect to.

The divider works like this:

- OA+ is biased to 0.3V by R10/R9.
  Vss = 3V3.
  R10/R9 junction is at 3V3 x R9/(R9 + R10) = 0.3V.

  This is a "pseudo ground" reference point so the op amp effectively has a +3V positive supply and a -0.3V negative supply relative to this point.

Negative feedback will now cause the opamp to adjust OA- to 0.3V - ie same as OA+.
For this to happen OA output must be > 0.3V so D1 will be negative biased in the typical reverse biased detector mode.

D1 current = R12 current =
(V_out - V_OA-) / R12 = (2.892 - 0.3) / 5.12MegOhm
=  493 nA

THe D1 model is probably wrong;y driven as it may assume as shown that D1 is forward biased. Swapping polarity of V2 should give 9 nA diode current is the source model is correct to produce as 9 nA diode current.
I_R2 = 50 mA and it is not 100% obvious how that translates to 9 nA.

IF I_D! = 9NA then IR12= 9nA so
V_R1 = IR = 9E-9 x 5.2E6 = 46.8 mV
So Vout = 0.3V + 0.0468V = 0.3468V.

---

Note: D1 current will also flow in R 9 but the resulting error voltage is so small as to be negligible.

Comment: Hi Russell, i know that a photo diode is a operates as reverse way, so the cathode is connect to - terminal of omp-amp. where dark current is located at cathode terminal.

Answer (score -1):

i use the Ad795, it ok with it. output voltage is 1.65v. [image]

Comment: using ad795, the the calculation result is very close.

Comment: AD795 won't work in this circuit - maybe if you give it +/-10 supplies.

Comment: What does this answer mean? What does the "is very close answer" mean? Where are you getting the 9 nA figure from? Why do you think this answer is OK and the last one is not? Do you understand the DC bias circuit and why it is used?

Comment: -1 I'll remove that and give it a +1 if you explain things properly. At present this answer appears to be rubbish. You say your target is 9 nA but this shows 232 nA. Closer to my calculated 493 nA in the prior example than to 9 nA.